# oracle regexp_replace to remove commas between Quote

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

Please can anybody help me out please. Have been trying for days to get a regexp_replace to remove commas between quotes irrespective of the commas position.
Example

```
cold, gold, "Block 12C, Jones Avenue, Broad Street, London", car
```

Expected Answer

```
cold, gold, "Block 12C Jones Avenue Broad Street London", car
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there at most one pair of doule quotes in a string?

Comment: If there are more than one pair of quotes,  can they be nested?

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the contents within double quotes(`REGEXP_SUBSTR`), replace the commas, and stuff it back to the old string using replace.

```
select REPLACE (whole_str,quoted_str,REPLACE (quoted_str,',')) FROM
(                
select 
    whole_str, 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR( whole_str, '^[^"]*("[^"]+")',1,1,NULL,1) quoted_str
  FROM yourtable
  );
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c75f/11)

Note that this could also be done using `INSTR`,`SUBSTR` which could be more efficient, but hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace` to get the desired output :

```
with t( id , val ) as(
select 1,'cold, gold, "Block 12C, Jones Avenue, Broad Street, London", car' from dual union
select 2,'"Block 12C, Jones Avenue, Broad Street, London", car, cold, gold' from dual )
select id, val value
  from t
 model dimension by( id ) measures( val )
 rules iterate(100)( val[any] = regexp_replace(val[cv()],',(([^"]*"){2})*([^"]*"[^"]*)$',' \1\3') );
```

[***d E m O***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2845/1)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there is a single regular expression function that will achieve the desired result. The "obvious" line of attack is to chop the input string into pieces and delete commas from each double-quoted substring as needed. (Unless each string has at most ONE double-quoted substring, in which case the problem has easier answers - but judging from the sample input string, it is possible that the same needs to be done for input strings with an arbitrary number of double-quoted substrings.)

Here is a solution using a recursive WITH clause - so it requires Oracle 11.2 or higher. (For earlier versions, a solution with a CONNECT BY hierarchical query can be used instead.) I wrote it with regular expressions, as requested; if speed becomes an issue, it can be re-written with standard INSTR, SUBSTR and REPLACE functions.

In the first factored subquery (subquery in the WITH clause) I created a few more inputs, to test whether the solution returns the correct result in different situations.

```
with
  inputs ( str ) as (
    select 'cold, gold, "Block 12C, Jones Ave., London", car' from dual union all
    select '"One, two, three","Four, five six,",'             from dual union all
    select 'No, double-quotes, in this, string'               from dual union all
    select 'No commas in "double quotes" here'                from dual
  ),
  r ( str, init, quoted, fin ) as (
    select  str, null, null, str
      from  inputs
    union all
    select  str, 
            init || replace(quoted, ',') || regexp_substr(fin, '[^"]*'),
            regexp_substr(fin, '"[^"]*"'),
            regexp_substr(fin, '([^"]*"){2}(.*)', 1, 1, null, 2)
      from  r
      where quoted is not null or fin is not null
  )
select str, init as new_str
from   r 
where  quoted is null and fin is null
;

STR                                           NEW_STR
--------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------
No, double-quotes, in this, string            No, double-quotes, in this, string
cold, gold, "Block 12C, Jay Ave, London", car cold, gold, "Block 12C Jay Ave London", car
No commas in "double quotes" here             No commas in "double quotes" here
"One, two, three","Four, five six,",          "One two three","Four five six",
```